# Is it possible to convert a hive table format to ORC and make it bucketed

Tags: hive, orc, acid

I have a set of hive tables that are not in ORC format and also not bucketed. I want to change their formats to ORC as well as make them bucketed. Couldn't find a concrete answer throughout the net. Any answer or guidance is appreciated. 
    Hive version is 2.3.5

Or if it is possible to do it in spark (pyspark or scala)?

The simplest solution would be to create a new table which is bucketed and is in ORC format then insert into it from the old table. Looking for an in-place solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create [bucketed table](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL+BucketedTables) and load data into it using INSERT OVERWRITE:

```
CREATE TABLE table_bucketed(col1 string, col2 string)
CLUSTERED BY(col1) INTO 10 BUCKETS
STORED AS ORC;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_bucketed
select ...
  from table_not_bucketed
```

See also [Sorted Bucketed Table.](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-BucketedSortedTables)

Comment: I created a new table in ORC format which is bucketed and inserted into it from an Avro format table. When i want to test the new table and select from it, it gives errors such as *Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error reading file:* and *Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Read past EOF for compressed stream Stream for column 44 kind DATA position: 0 length: 0 range: 0 offset: 0 limit: 0*

Comment: at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:121)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:77)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.doNextWithExceptionHandler(HadoopShimsSecure.java:232)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.next(HadoopShimsSecure.java:142)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)

Comment: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:459)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:177)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:171)

Comment: at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:121)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:77)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:365)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.doNext(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:167)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.doNext(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:52)

Comment: at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.next(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:116)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.doNextWithExceptionHandler(HadoopShimsSecure.java:229)

Comment: at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1191)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.ensureBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:77)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.hasNext(RecordReaderImpl.java:93)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$OrcRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:238)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$OrcRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:213)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:360)

Comment: at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readFully(SerializationUtils.java:119)
 at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readLongLE(SerializationUtils.java:102)
 at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readDouble(SerializationUtils.java:98)
 at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$DoubleTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:762)
 at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:1833)
 at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$ListTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:2001)

Comment: at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextBatch(TreeReaderFactory.java:1815)
 at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1184)

Answer (score 2):

**Hive:**
Use a staging table to read the un-bucketed data (assuming `TEXTFILE` format) using these commands:

```
CREATE TABLE staging_table(
    col1 colType, 
    col2 colType, ...
    coln colType
)
STORED AS 
    TEXTFILE
LOCATION 
    '/path/of/input/data';

CREATE TABLE target_table(
    col1 colType, 
    col2 colType, ...
    coln colType
)
CLUSTERED BY(col1) INTO 10 BUCKETS
STORED AS ORC;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_bucketed
SELECT 
    col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM 
    staging_table;
```

The same can be done in `**Spark** DataFrame APIs` (assuming `CSV` format) like this:

```
df = spark.read.format("csv")
          .option("inferSchema", "true")
          .option("header", "true")
          .option("delimiter", ",")
          .option("path", "/path/of/input/data/")
          .load()

df.write.format("orc")
        .option("path", "/path/of/output/data/")
        .save()
```

Comment: This is not an in-place solution. I already knew how to create a table and insert into it.

Comment: If you  meant about changing the storage format of an existing Hive table (for instance from TEXTFILE to ORC) and making it bucketted, then Hive doesn't support this. However, if your existing table is external table, then you can use  Spark to change the storage format and path in such a way so that the target path is same as the path of this external table. And then, you can alter table command to change the table SerDe from SimpleSerDe2 to ORC. But you would still not able to make the table bucketted though.

Comment: So it's possible that table's storage type can be change data format indirectly (using Hive/Spark for format and path manipulation), but an existing non-bucketted table cannot be converted to bucketted.